# How to write $a^{ix}$ in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

We know that $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ and the plot of $2^{ix}$ seems to have sinusoidal behavior.

http://goo.gl/Xfg2wp

Can we claim that we can write $a^{ix}$ in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:If $a>0$ then $a=e^{\ln a}$

Comment: $a=e^{\ln a}$ is true for negative values of a: $(a=e^{\ln a}, a\neq 0)$.

Comment: sure log can be defined for complex numbers but wont be single valued anymore

Comment: $e^{\ln(a)}$ is single valued for $a \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$a=e^{\ln a}, a>0$

$$(e^{\ln a})^{ix}=e^{ix \ln a}=\cos(x \ln a)+i\sin(x\ln a)$$